# Passing array with parameters to Model in Codeigniter 4

Tags: sql, arrays, model, codeigniter-4

I tryng to pass an array of values from my controller to the model

My controller:

```
$arr_list = array('O','N','H'); 
$data['lista'] = $getmodel->query_list($arr_list1);
```

My model

```
public function query_list($list = '', $limit = 10, $lang = 'en')
{
    
$query = "SELECT tab1.id, name FROM tab_name";

$a = 0;
    
   foreach( $list as $value)  
        {  
           if ($value != ''){
               
            if ($a == 0){
            $query .= " AND (field = '".$value."' "; 
            }
            else
            {
             $query .= " OR field = '".$value."' ";  
            }
                
            $a = $a + 1; 
         }
      }

$query .= " ORDER BY RAND() "; 
}
```

I receive the error: Array to string conversion

This code works perfectly in CI 2 but does not work on CI4.

Why?

Comment: 1. Where do you get the error? 2.Your function - query_list() does not return anything. 3. Where have you defined $arr_list1? It's nowhere to be seen. 4. Are you sure this worked "perfectly" in CI 2????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of bugs in yours the code, but I'll try to help.

[Docs CI4: $builder->whereIn()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Generates a WHERE field IN (‘item’, ‘item’) SQL query joined with AND if appropriate

```
$names = ['Frank', 'Todd', 'James'];
$builder->whereIn('username', $names);
// Produces: WHERE username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

Controller

```
$this->data['return'] = $HotelModel->test(['1', '2', '3', '4']);
```

Model

```
public function test($array)
{
    return $this->db->table('tab_name')->whereIn('column',$array)->get()->getResultObject();
}
```

Result last_query

```
SELECT * FROM 'tab_name' WHERE 'column' IN ('1', '2', '3', '4')
```